# adding DB::raw within laravel join clause

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I need help getting this to work. Created_at field is date_time so I cannot the fetch the those records which has valid time like this. (2016-08-19 09:33:41).

```
$assets = DB::table('assets')
                ->join('printer_readings', function($join) use ($date){
                    $join->on('assets.id', '=', 'printer_readings.asset_id')
                        ->where('printer_readings.created_at', '=', $date);
                })
                ->where('branch_id', $this->branch_id)
                ->where('type', 'printer')
                ->selectRaw('name, serial, assets.id, assets.prev, current, DATE(printer_readings.created_at) as date')
                ->orderBy('date')
                ->get();
```

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot fetch those records? Do you mean that `DATE(printer_readings.created_at)` is not returning the date only?

Comment: i'm referring to "where" under join clause

Comment: What is `$date` then?

Comment: Check your $date variable. If your $data value is just 2016-08-19 then the comparison would be like 2016-08-19 00:00:00.

Comment: @MaxGaurav I want to be able to get even those records 2016-08-19 22:32:14 ... How can I do that?

Comment: I am assuming your $date is just 2016-08-19 and to solve the problem you just need to make the `$date = $date . " 23:59:59"` and then use it.